# Save form item properties to text file

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm a beginner trying to write a method to save forms item properties into a text file.I think my loop have some issues.

```
public void SaveFormItems(object sender, List<IFormItem> Items,string fileName)
  {        
        string fn = path+fileName+".txt";
        string[] content = null; 
        string[] line = null;
        int count = Items.Count; ;
        for (int i = 1; i < count; i++)
        {
            foreach (var ctrl in Items)
            {
                content[0] = ctrl.Id.ToString();
                content[1] = ctrl.Type.GetTypeCode().ToString();
                content[2] = ctrl.X.ToString();
                content[3] = ctrl.Y.ToString();
                content[4] = ctrl.Height.ToString();
                content[5] = ctrl.Width.ToString();
                content[6] = ctrl.Text.ToString();

                line[i] = String.Join("/t", content);
            }



            if (!File.Exists(fn))
            {
                File.WriteAllLines(path, line, Encoding.UTF8);
            }
        } 

    }
```

The Output text file must contain each item property in separate lines as

```
FormName
Text    1   500 100 30  200 0   User ID
TextInput   2   700 100 30  200 0   UsesrId
Text    3   500 150 30  200 0   First Name
TextInput   4   700 150 30  200 0   FirstName
```

Comment: You need to initialize your arrays to start with `content = new string[7];`. Your loop should also be zero based `for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)`.

Comment: Can you describe the specific issue you're encountering? Is it not compiling, does it encounter an exception at runtime, or is it otherwise not behaving as you expect?

Comment: Actually I'm running an isolated projected and I'm writing Test methods to test it.

Comment: the issue happens @runtime

Comment: @JRU - That could mean that either you're encountering an unhandled exception (in which case you should share what it is) or it just isn't behaving as you would expect (in which case you should share its behavior compared to what is expected). Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you.

```
public void SaveFormItems(object sender, List<IFormItem> Items,string fileName)
  {        
        string fn = path+fileName+".txt";
        string[] content = new string[7]; 
        string[] line = null;
        foreach (var ctrl in Items)
            {
                content[0] = ctrl.Id.ToString();
                content[1] = ctrl.Type.GetTypeCode().ToString();
                content[2] = ctrl.X.ToString();
                content[3] = ctrl.Y.ToString();
                content[4] = ctrl.Height.ToString();
                content[5] = ctrl.Width.ToString();
                content[6] = ctrl.Text.ToString();

                line[i] = String.Join("/t", content);

                if (!File.Exists(fn))
                   {
                      File.WriteAllLines(path, line, Encoding.UTF8);
                   }
            }
  }
```